# Javascript n months after today

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the day 90 days after today. This is my code:

```
var today = new Date();
var threeMonthsFromToday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 90));
```

When I print `threeMonthsFromToday`, I get the correct date: `2017-04-24T15:17:42.641Z`. However, when I try to reformat the date to be in the form `dd/mm/yyyy` using this code:

```
var day = ('0' + threeMonthsFromToday.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ('0' + threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth() + 1).slice(-2);
var year = threeMonthsFromToday.getFullYear();
var date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
```

I get a completely different and invalid date: `24/31/2017`.

I have been debugging this for hours and still can't seem to figure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Consider using moment.js :)

Comment: I agree with above ref to moment.js as you now need to consider 90 days is not exactly three months etc.. A Lot of headaches can be avoided.

Comment: @Pogrindis—moment.js doesn't help at all with that. The issue here actually has nothing to do with dates, it's about incorrect use of the "+" punctuator.

Comment: @RobG I understand the problem in the question, but on review of it's intended use, it's a little uncomfortable to my eye.

Comment: @Pogrindis—I'm a little uncomfortable with using a library fix an issue that is unrelated to said library . ;-)

Comment: Touché @RobG! Touché indeed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, `'0' + threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth()` give you a string : `"03"` then you add `1` converted to string giving you `"031"` for month before slice.

Use this :

```
var month = ('0' + (threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
```

Comment: Good explanation.

Comment: I can't believe I wasted this much time on such a rookie mistake :D
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the basic BODMAS rule here please modify your code as follows

```
    var today = new Date();
var threeMonthsFromToday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 90));
var day = ('0' + threeMonthsFromToday.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ('0' + (threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var year = threeMonthsFromToday.getFullYear();
var date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
```

the operations are performed from left to right, so month is getting converted to string before being added to a number. Including a bracket will first perform operation inside bracket and then make it a string

Comment: It'd be nice to include a snippet about why BODMAs are hurting OP. Especially since I hadn't heard that term before, only Order of Operations.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)?

```
threeMonthsFromToday.toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
```

Comment: The result of *toLocaleString* is completely implementation dependent and may produce a different result in different hosts. It doesn't produce the OP's required result in Safari, Firefox or Chrome. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Below does the trick for you ...
getMonth() +1 before adding the "0" to it so that you get an arithematic +1

```js
var today = new Date();
var threeMonthsFromToday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 90));
var day = ('0' + threeMonthsFromToday.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ('0' + (threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
var year = threeMonthsFromToday.getFullYear();
var date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
console.log(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var day = threeMonthsFromToday.getDate()
if(day < 10){
    day = '0' + day
}
var month = threeMonthsFromToday.getMonth()+1
if(month<10){
    month = '0' + month
}
var year = threeMonthsFromToday.getFullYear()
var date = day + '/' + month + '/' + year
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple ***toLocaleDateString*** method

The toLocaleDateString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the date portion of this date.

```js
var today = new Date();
var threeMonthsFromToday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 90));

var date = threeMonthsFromToday.toLocaleDateString();

console.log(date);
```

```
//result in console : "24/04/2017"
```

Try it out on your console.

Comment: *toLocaleString* returns an **implementation dependent** string, so different results in different hosts and may ignore system preferences for date formatting entirely (e.g. Chrome). Where ECMA-402 extensions are not used or supported, [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) says: "*The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form that corresponds to the conventions of the host environment's current locale.*"